# Expand multiple WPF Expander sections

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an expander in WPF, and I am wondering how you make it so you can expand multiple areas at one time. Every time I click on a section, the previously opened section closes. I want that to remain open. Is there a way to do that? This expander is in a ListBox, that is why there are multiples of them.

Comment: This is a WPF Expander, this sounds like a 3rd party accordian (type) control.  The WPF expander AFAIK only has a single content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As long as you don't set the IsExpanded property, you are fine.